# Не определяется библиотека Selenium в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Установил selenium через `pip install selenium` он установился, отображается в `pip list`, но когда я пишу в коде `from selenium` у меня не определяет то, что у меня есть selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вероятно создали виртуальное окружение в PyCharm (он сам предлагает это сделать). И поэтому Selenium нужно установить через:

File -> Settings... -> Project: Python -> Project Interpreted -> (по умолчанию будет выбрано созданное виртуальное окружение) -> Нажать "+" с правой стороны окна -> Ввести "Selenium" в строку поиска -> Install Package

Answer (score -1):

Я устанавливаю все библиотеки в Windows 8.1 через: Win+X на клавиатуре/Командная строка   и там pip install selenium или сто-то иное.
Все установленные библиотеки у меня доступны во всех проектах PyCharm.

Comment: Это неправильный подход. Вы засоряете библиотеками всю систему, а через виртуальное окружение нужная вам библиотека будет для одного проекта.

Comment: Спасибо за урок для новичка. Я работаю в PyCharm, там вроде для каждого проекта свое виртуальное окружение. Т.е. нужно устанавливать в консоли PyCharm?

Comment: Да, именно так. В каждом проекте будут только стандартные библиотеки, нужную устанавливаешь через pip install, как обычно